# Is there a way to return a specific subclass of multiple options and save it in an attribute?

Tags: java, variables, generics

i have to model a post office for a school exercise where different persons can login and use methods. So there is a class Person with the subclasses Employee and Customer and the class Employee has the subclasses Agent and MailMan. My problem now is that I have a method which checks with a username and a password for the corresponding person and saves this person in a variable, but the variable doesnt know which of the subclasses will be safed, so I cant use methods with that variable.

```
private Person personWhoIsLoggedIn; //I try to use methods from the subclasses from Person with this variable


    public void authenticate(String username, String password) {
    if(!isLoggedIn) {
        if(checkAgentLogin(username,password) != null) {
            personWhoIsLoggedIn = checkAgentLogin(username,password);
            isLoggedIn = true;
        }
        if(checkMailManLogin(username,password) != null) {
            personWhoIsLoggedIn = checkMailManLogin(username,password);
            isLoggedIn = true;
        }
        if(checkCustomerLogin(username,password) != null) {
            personWhoIsLoggedIn = checkCustomerLogin(username,password);
            isLoggedIn = true;
        }
    }
}
postOffice.getPersonWhoIsLoggedIn().sendMail(parameters[0], parameters[1], parameters[2]); //sendMail is a method I try to use in my main with the variable
```

So do you know a way to make the variable generic or should I edit the methods and try another solution?
Thank you for the help.

Cheers,
Pokelex

Comment: The code you provide is not enough to understand what you're trying to achieve exactly. Where does it matter what subclass it is?

Comment: well my goal is to use the attribute personWhoIsLoggedIn to use methods with that person in my main, but because the methods are different in the different subclasses I cant use those methods with the variable, ill try to provide more code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, I think a general way to implement this is to create a set of Roles or Permissions that provide the feature of "being allowed to do something". The `Person` class then can have the method `getPermissions()` which defines what a logged in user can do.

```
class Person {
  public List<Permission> getPermissions() {
    return List.of(Permission.EVERYONE);
  }
}
```

The subclasses can then override this method to add their own permissions.

```
class Employee {
  public List<Permission> getPermissions() {
    // make sure the permissions from employee don't get lost
    List<Permission> result = new ArrayList<>(super.getPermissions());
    // add the additional permissions
    result.add(Permission.EMPLOYEE);
    return result;
  }
}
```

Then, at the point you evaluate a logged in user, you check the permissions they have and change behavior accordingly.

```
void showMenu(Person currentUser) {
  List<Permission> permissions = currentUser.getPermissions();
  if (permissions.contains(Permission.EVERYONE)) {
    // show "edit own details" or something
  }
  if (permissions.contains(Permission.EMPLOYEE)) {
    // show "get last paycheck" (?)
  }
}
```

There are more elegant ways to implement this, but the point here is that the `Permission` creates an abstraction that can be reused in other contexts. For example, this way you don't need to implement the "what menu items can a person display" in the `Person` class hierarchy, which would overcrowd it in the long run.

Comment: That's a nice approach as well. Roles simplify and even make it extensible to future new roles with minimum impact to the original auth logic.

Answer (score 0):

as a first iteration, since there are better ways to improve it, you can make `Person` an abstract class and then add abstract methods that are common to all the subclasses e.g.

```
public abstract class Person {

    public abstract void method1();
    
    public abstract void method2();
}
```

Then in the subclass you implement them

```
public class Customer extends Person {

    public void method1() {
        // do something
    }
    
    public void method2() {
        // do something
    }
}
```

and in your original code, you can reference persons like:

`Person personWhoIsLoggedIn = checkAgentLogin(username,password);`

As I mentioned before, there are more efficient ways to achieve what you want but you can start simple and improve.

Comment: My problem in the original Code is, that the Methods like checkAgentLogin(username,password) only return a subclass from Person so I cant save the return values into a Person variable

Comment: As far as I understood, with the proposed approach, you can make `checkAgentLogin(..)` return type as `Person`. If you need a specific method of a subclass that is not known by `Person`, you can use type cast, e.g. `((Agent) personWhoIsLoggedIn).specificMethod()`.

Answer (score -1):

You should check design patterns for this kind of behavior. You can use the strategy pattern or any other best fit.

Start from [this](https://stackabuse.com/behavioral-design-patterns-in-java/).